# Is there any function (language doesn't matter), to make automated trim a polygon from PDF?

Tags: pdf

I work with some PDF's, and need automatized trimming of PDF content. in separate layers i have image and outlines, and i want to trim interior of that outlines from image.

1. Image layer is drawing that consist of different colors
2. Outline is always red, closed contour.

Is it possible or not?
If yes, what language/framework should i use?

Thx in advance

[ex. image with outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SYYn.png)

Comment: Do you want to remove the red outline or do you want to remove the content that appears inside the red outline?

Comment: @iPDFdev PDF consist of technical drawing. red outlines mark changes, and i have to print them, keeping dimensions, cause they will be applied to existing big drawings.. i want to copy the red outline, with the content that appears inside, in a new PDF, and it has to keep dimensions. remained content doesn't matter, i need just these outlines. now i just print each outline on A4, but i want to save paper, and time. i work on Windows, if matters